# Paragraph indents dissapear after table

Tags: tables, indentation

My problem is that after I put a table in my document all paragraphs after it dissapear. I tried to solve this by using `\justify` but it seems to not work on first paragraph and it breaks something with `\wrapfigure` environment. Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\newgeometry{tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
%\usepackage{array}
%\RaggedRightParindent = 15 pt
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}


%\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%opening
\title{Opracohdfhdfdhfghhdhd3}
\author{Alicja }

\begin{document}
\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1,3}



\include{strona_tytulowa}


\newpage

\include{streszczenie}

\include{wstep_teor}


\include{opracowanie}
\include{opracowanie_2}

\include{wyniki}


\include{wnioski}
```

Here is a fragment of the code:

```
\section{Opracowanie procedury badawczej}

\subsection{Opis aparatury}

\indent

Wytwarzanie cienkich warstw i badania spektroskopowe to procesy, które muszą być przeprowadzanie w specjalnie przygotowanych systemach utrzymujących różnego rodzaju próżnię. Próżnia, w mechanice klasycznej, to obszar, w którym nie ma żadnych zdolnych do oddziaływania ze sobą ciał. W technice, pod pojęciem próżni rozumie się rozrzedzony gaz. Nie występuje ogólnie przyjęta granica ciśnienia między ośrodkiem gazowym, a próżnią. Ustalone są jednak zwyczajowe przedziały ciśnienia dla różnych rodzajów próżni. 


\captionof{table}{Rodzaje próżni. Zwyczajowo stosowane jednostki ciśnienia w technologii próżniowej: 1 mbar = $1 * 10 ^2 $ Pa, 1 torr $\approx $1,333 mbar}
\label{tab:proznia}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Rodzaj próżni & Niska & Średnia & Wysoka & Ultra wysoka & Ekstremalnie wysoka \\ 
    \hline 
    \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} P, Pa & 30,000...100 & 100...$10^{-1}$ & $10^{-1}$...$10^{-5}$ & $10^{-5}$...$10^{-10}$ & <$10^{-10}$ \\  
    \hline 
    \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} P, mbar & 300...1 & 1...$10^{-3}$ & $10^{-3}$...$10^{-7}$ & $10^{-7}$...$10^{-12}$ & <$10^{-12}$\\
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}


Kluczowymi parametrami dla zagadnienia cienkich warstw i ich analizy są średnia droga swobodna, ilość cząsteczek zderzająca się z powierzchnią próbki w ciągu sekundy oraz ilość tworzących się jednoatomowych warstw na powierzchni w ciągu sekundy. Średnia droga swobodna definiowana jest jako średnia droga przebywana przez cząstkę w ośrodku przed zderzeniem z inną cząstką tego ośrodka. W teorii kinetycznej gazów określana jest wzorem: 


\begin{equation}
\lambda = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \pi n_{0} d^{2}}}
\label{sr_en}
\end{equation}

{\footnotesize  Gdzie: $n_0$ - koncentracja cząsteczek gazu, d - efektywna średnica cząsteczki.} 



\noindent Przykładowe wartości wymienionych kluczowych parametrów zamieszczam w tabeli.\\




\subsubsection{Pompy próżniowe}

\indent


Do osiągania odpowiedniej wartości ciśnienia w układzie używany jest szereg pomp. Ze względu na mechanikę działa możemy je podzielić na pompy:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Wiążące} (pułapkowe), \\
    np. kriopompa, tytanowa pompa sublimacyjna.

    \item \textbf{Transferujące}, które dzielimy na:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Kinetyczne}, \\
        np. pompa turbomolekularna, pompa dyfuzyjna.
        \item \textbf{Wypierające}, \\
        np. pompa skrolowa, pompa śrubowa.

    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
```

And this is how it looks with and without a table.

[image: page with the table]

There are no more indents in whole document after this.

[image: page without a table]

I tried everything I found on the internet and I couldn't solve this. Does anyone know how to fix it?

---

Example and resulting output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\newgeometry{tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
%\usepackage{array}
%\RaggedRightParindent = 15 pt
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}



%\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%opening
\title{Opracohdfhdfdhfghhdhd3}
\author{Alicja }

\begin{document}
\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1,3}



\section{Opracowanie procedury badawczej}

\subsection{Opis aparatury}

\indent

Wytwarzanie cienkich warstw i badania spektroskopowe to procesy, które muszą być przeprowadzanie w specjalnie przygotowanych systemach utrzymujących różnego rodzaju próżnię. Próżnia, w mechanice klasycznej, to obszar, w którym nie ma żadnych zdolnych do oddziaływania ze sobą ciał. W technice, pod pojęciem próżni rozumie się rozrzedzony gaz. Nie występuje ogólnie przyjęta granica ciśnienia między ośrodkiem gazowym, a próżnią. Ustalone są jednak zwyczajowe przedziały ciśnienia dla różnych rodzajów próżni. 


\captionof{table}{Rodzaje próżni. Zwyczajowo stosowane jednostki ciśnienia w technologii próżniowej: 1 mbar = $1 * 10 ^2 $ Pa, 1 torr $\approx $1,333 mbar}
\label{tab:proznia}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Rodzaj próżni & Niska & Średnia & Wysoka & Ultra wysoka & Ekstremalnie wysoka \\ 
    \hline 
    \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} P, Pa & 30,000...100 & 100...$10^{-1}$ & $10^{-1}$...$10^{-5}$ & $10^{-5}$...$10^{-10}$ & <$10^{-10}$ \\  
    \hline 
    \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} P, mbar & 300...1 & 1...$10^{-3}$ & $10^{-3}$...$10^{-7}$ & $10^{-7}$...$10^{-12}$ & <$10^{-12}$\\
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}


Kluczowymi parametrami dla zagadnienia cienkich warstw i ich analizy są średnia droga swobodna, ilość cząsteczek zderzająca się z powierzchnią próbki w ciągu sekundy oraz ilość tworzących się jednoatomowych warstw na powierzchni w ciągu sekundy. Średnia droga swobodna definiowana jest jako średnia droga przebywana przez cząstkę w ośrodku przed zderzeniem z inną cząstką tego ośrodka. W teorii kinetycznej gazów określana jest wzorem: 


\begin{equation}
\lambda = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \pi n_{0} d^{2}}}
\label{sr_en}
\end{equation}

{\footnotesize  Gdzie: $n_0$ - koncentracja cząsteczek gazu, d - efektywna średnica cząsteczki.} 



\noindent Przykładowe wartości wymienionych kluczowych parametrów zamieszczam w tabeli.\\




\subsubsection{Pompy próżniowe}

\indent


Do osiągania odpowiedniej wartości ciśnienia w układzie używany jest szereg pomp. Ze względu na mechanikę działa możemy je podzielić na pompy:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Wiążące} (pułapkowe), \\
    np. kriopompa, tytanowa pompa sublimacyjna.

    \item \textbf{Transferujące}, które dzielimy na:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Kinetyczne}, \\
        np. pompa turbomolekularna, pompa dyfuzyjna.
        \item \textbf{Wypierające}, \\
        np. pompa skrolowa, pompa śrubowa.

    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you never need to use `\indent` (and in your case you leave  a paragraph break after `\indent` so it just makes a spurious empty paragraph with no text) and you never need `\justify` that is the tex default.

Comment: never leave a blank line before a display math such as `\begin{equation}` Note we can only make general comments on the code posted as you have not provided any code we can run to see the problem. Please edit the question to make a small sel contained complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: I added a complete test document made by joining your fragments and removing inclusion of files that are not provided. there are some markup errors as described above but it runs without error and produces the expected output as shown, which indents do you find missing?

Answer (score 2):

You get the warning

```
Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof
(caption)                outside box or environment on input line 56.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Never ignore warnings, this is telling you that the paragraph indent (and other things) will be messed up.

Move the `\captionof` inside the `center` enviornment.